# Как узнать что изменило HTML элемент?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox, отладка

При клике на одну из кнопок на сайте исчезает другая кнопка. (`display:none`)
Так не должно быть, и не могу найти код где это делается!

В консоли *Google Chrome* и *Mozzila Firefox* не нашел...

Проект большой. В поиске по файлам искал... ничего...магия....

Comment: Смотрите обработчик события для данной кнопки, которую кликаете. Возможно она меняет какой-нибудь атрибут у другой кнопки. или элемент стиля

Comment: Смотрел, не меняет!

Comment: Тоже интересно. Иногда приходится совершать большие танцы с бубном и фаербагом, чтобы найти обработчик.

Comment: Обработчиков у кнопки может быть несколько. Посмотрите все. Также может какой-нибудь таймаут устанавливается.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

В Google Chrome это делается очень просто:

Открываете Developer Tools(F12), инструментом выбора(CTRL+SHIFT+C) находите нужный элемент, и в контекстом меню этого элемента в дереве элементов выбираете функцию "Break On", c необходимым условием - при изменении подэлементов, изменении атрибутов или удалении элемента.

При соответствующем изменении, отладчик JavaScript остановится на строчке кода, которая это изменение вызвала.

[image: функция Break On в Google Chrome Devleoper Tools]

Comment: Да!!! Спасибо! Оно!!!... как долго я не знал о этом функионале!!!!

Comment: @myvzar, а ещё в Google Chrome есть [Workspaces](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/setup/setup-workflow?hl=en), что позволяет использовать его в качестве полноценной IDE для фронтенда и вполне себе удобного редактора для бекенда :) Очень многие вообще не знают об его существовании, выполняя правки по принципу "поменял в Chrome, скопировал в редактор, сохранил, обновил, поменял в Chrome, скопировал, сохранил, обновил, ..." :))

Answer (score 7):

Для полноты картины, то же самое легко делается и в Firefox с плагином Firebug.

Та же комбинация клавиш: F12 открывает Firebug, Ctrl-Shift-C или инструмент выбора

[image: инструмент выбора]

позволяют найти элемент в дереве, правая кнопка мыши на элемент открывает меню, в котором можно выбрать остановку на изменении:

[image: остановка на изменениях]

Comment: А без Firebug'а нельзя?

Comment: @Qwertiy: насколько я понимаю, нет. Но кто ж отлаживает без него?

Comment: Я ​​​​​​​​​​​:)

Comment: @Qwertiy: Немедленно прекращайте!

Comment: @VladD, можно пойти извращенным путем - через создание MutationObserver в той-же консоли(выбрав DOM-элемент через JQuery, например), запихав внутрь callback-а остановку отладчика JS, либо что-то другое. ☺️ Хотя это больше при автоматизации тестирования полезно.

Comment: @SergeyRufanov: Можно, но зачем?